# How to start from a certain row and end in a certain row in mysql PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to start from a certain row and end in a certain row in mysql ?

Example :

> row 1 - Mike
>
> row 2 - ayman
>
> row 3 - kayla ---> i want to start from here
>
> row 4 - polat
>
> row 5 - ninety
>
> row 6 - Okamou
>
> row 7 - Sakura
>
> row 8 - kall ---> i want to end here
>
> row 9 - kopa
>
> row 10 - Traas

what i'm using is:

```
Select name, number, id from usernames_table LIMIT 3,8
```

This is just an example, In my real application i want to start from row number 2000 and end in row 6000 which is not the end of the table.

I used `LIMIT starthere, endhere` but it gives me some extra rows i don't know why?

Please help ?

Comment: Show your `limit` usage. There is no `endhere` that is how many rows to show.

Comment: If you don't have an explicit ID column then `LIMIT` is the way to go.

Comment: Instead of showing us `LIMIT starthere, endhere`, show the actual `LIMIT`.

Comment: If you did `limit 2,8` that is incorrect. That will show you rows starting at 3 and then 8 rows. You'd want `limit 2,5` i think..

Comment: You can use LIMIT 4000 OFFSET 2000, but that assumes you know where to start and have written ORDER BY appropriately.
Are you really hard coding the OFFSET and LIMIT though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `limit` incorrectly. This:

```
Select name, number, id from usernames_table LIMIT 3,8
```

says to start at row 4 and end after 8 rows have been selected.

Try:

```
Select name, number, id from usernames_table LIMIT 2,6
```

This says start after row 2, and return 6 rows (so 3-8).

Further information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

... or for your real application:

```
Select name, number, id from usernames_table LIMIT 1999,4000
```

which says start at 2000 and return 4000 rows (so end at 6000, assuming rows weren't deleted..).

Comment: Hey chris85 and what if the user want to select that, i have two inputs start and end so the sql query should be like this : select name from table where LIMIT $start - 1,$end/2 ??

Comment: Make sure `$start` is greater than 1. The dividing by 2 won't work, look at your `8` issue divide by 2 there and you get 4, not 5. You might want to consider using a `where` with `between` if there are ids.

Comment: @chris85, don't you mean "limit 2,6"? From rites 3 to 8 there are 6 rows, not 5.

Comment: @NunoPereira oh yea, guess I miscounted. Thanks.